# Friction component?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, vectors

[image]

Why is the component of contact force is not like contact force cos theta and contact force sin theta but here they have no trigonometric values like we normally make components for a force.Like F
contact
cosθ
F
c
o
n
t
a
c
t
cos
⁡
θ
and
F
contact
sinθ
F
c
o
n
t
a
c
t
sin
⁡
θ
.Since here we have normal force and friction.Why is that?

Comment: That's just how contact force is defined. It is the resultant of forces acting on the object due to the surface. For example: if there was no friction, F would have no horizontal component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the component of contact force is not like $F_{contact} \cos \theta$ and $F_{contact} \sin \theta$ but here they have no trigonometric values like we normally make components for a force. Like $F \cos \theta$ and $F \sin \theta$.

They are still the components of the contact force and that's why you get a relation between the normal force and the friction force i.e. $F_{friction} = \mu F_{Normal}$ .

But since we don't know the magnitude of this contact force and also the angle at which it acts (**since there are lots of factors affecting this contact force like the amount and orientation of the charges in the molecules of the surfaces in contact , the exact amount of foreign atoms like atoms of air between the surfaces in contact and many other things**) , we generally call them as Normal force and frictional force. And regard them differently but they are still the components of that contact force.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: Why is it that we don’t know the magnitude of contact force

Comment: @robert patrick because there are lots of factors affecting that force. At basic level , the cause of contact force is the electromagnetic forces but to calculate the magnitude of this force we need to know about the charge distribution  and suppose we somehow managed to know the quantity of charges between the surfaces in contact then how can we surely say that there is no impurities between the surfaces or no foreign atoms like atoms of air between the surfaces. Because of these factors we can't calculate the magnitude of the contact force.

Comment: @robert patrick was that helpful ?

Comment: Yes and why don’t we know the angle.Since we know normal is perpendicular and friction is horizontal.So contact force should be at 45 degree as if it is the slope of normal and friction force.So we don’t we know the angle then?

Comment: @robert patrick the angle is 45° only when both normal and friction force are of same magnitude i.e. $\mu =1$ . It is not necessary that they are at 45° and again it depends upon the orientation of the charges in the two surfaces and hence the angles can be different.

Comment: Thank you I have understood it now

Comment: @robert patrick glad to know :)